# sending and receiving numpy arrays / js typed arrays over binary protocol

Tags: javascript, python, numpy, websocket

I have a python application that uses numpy arrays heavily. I'd like to run a python websocket server that runs this application concurrently so that I can interact with it from a web browser client using javascript and websockets. The arrays I want to send are usually `float32`s or `uint`s, and it's not uncommon for my application to have arrays with thousands of elements. Is the current websockets standard appropriate for this? I believe it's possible to send binary data, but I don't know about the overhead and I don't know what's the best approach to efficiently convert and send a numpy array to a js client expecting a typed array (Float32Array for example). Are there any libraries or some standard methods to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I would look into Google's protobufs: https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/overview

Comment: It seems there's no official support for JavaScript though.

Comment: There is ... I used to work there and used JS with protobufs https://github.com/google/protobuf/tree/master/js

Comment: My bad. I jumped to conclusions too quickly after looking at the tutorials section.